# Load scheduler units view with database values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

Hi I am using dhtmlx scheduler with mvc razor.

I have create the units tab. But i am not getting how to divide the events across different units. Here is my sample code.

```
Scheduler.InitialDate = DateTime.Now.Date;// the initial data of Scheduler   
var unit = new UnitsView("Employee", "EmpID");//initializes the view
var rooms = new List<object>(){
    new { key = "1", label = "Employee1"},
    new { key = "2", label = "Employee2"},
    new { key = "3", label = "Employee3"},
    new { key = "4", label = "Employee4"}
};
unit.AddOptions(rooms);
Scheduler.Views.Add(unit);
```

I get the ID and display name through a stored procedure,
Now I have the problem in setting the `key=ID` and `label= displayname`.

Please help me displaying the names in the scheduler unitsview.
I use entity database first in mvc3 razor

Here is the code I tried already but struck in the middle ,

```
var unit = new UnitsView("units", "resourcename");
scheduler.Views.Add(unit);
List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result> resourcedisplayname = 
           new List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result>();
resourcedisplayname = _scheduler.Getresorderdisplay();
DashboardViewModel objDashboardViewModel = new DashboardViewModel();
var options = new List<object>();
//how to add key and label from the result i'm getting from resourcedisplayname?

unit.AddOptions(options);
```

>

```
public partial class GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

model:

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
    //scheduler unitsview
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

this is where I get Id and display name from the storedprocedure

```
public List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result> Getresorderdisplay()
{
    List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result> oGetresorderdisplay = 
                  new List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result>();

    oGetresorderdisplay = dbContext.GetResourceOrderDisplay().ToList();

    return oGetresorderdisplay.ToList();
}
```

Thankyou PKKG for your time :) 
I got this solved. here is the solution, please leave comments below for improvement :)
**Solution:**

```
     var unit = new UnitsView("units", "ID");
...............
......

         var options = new List<object>();
                      foreach (var name in resourcedisplayname)
                      {


   options.Add(new { key = name.ID, label = name.DisplayName });
                  }
                unit.AddOptions(options);
```

Comment: Can you use View Model instead of Anonymous Type ?